# Getting attribute name rather than value with BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have managed to pull out most of the various attributes of a site I am scraping, but have come short trying to extract the value of something within the div declarator itself.

Specifically, assuming the following:

```
<div class="item" data-color="red" data-itemid="abc">Red Slippers</div>
```

I am after the value inside data-itemid > abc.

I cannot seem to get something that isn't looking at the value inside the div: i.e. Red Slippers, which is not what I am after.

I have tried the following, without luck:

`item_id = soup.find('data-itemid')`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `find_all` with a predicate to narrow your search, and then access that particular attribute with dict-like indexing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html5lib')

items = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'item'})
for item in items:
    print(item['data-itemid'])
```

If you wish to further narrow down your search, you can just add more predicates to your dict, like this:

```
{'class' : 'item', 'data-color' : 'red', ...} # and so on
```

Comment: @NickP: `html5lib` might not be installed. You may need to download it.